# How to pass BindingResult as request param?

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, mockito

I want to test this method by MockMvc

```
    @RequestMapping("/saveCandidate")
        public String saveCandidate(
                Model model,
                @ModelAttribute("candidateFromRequest") @Validated()  Candidate candidateFromRequest,
                BindingResult result,
                @ModelAttribute("skillsIdList") Set<Skill> skills,
                @ModelAttribute("vacanciesForCandidate") Set<Vacancy> vacanciesForCandidate,
                @ModelAttribute("eventsForCandidate") Set<Event> eventsForCandidate,
                RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
...


}
```

How Can I pass mock of BindingResult result from test method to `saveCandidate` method?

my test method:

```
        @Test
            public void saveCandidateWithErrors() throws Exception{
                BindingResult result= mock(BindingResult.class);

                when(result.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);
                when(candidateService.findByName(anyString())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Candidate>());

                MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/saveCandidate");
         if(result.hasErrors())
                  //how test code that writing here?
        }
         else{
             //I always hit it here
       }
}
```

I want to set to reqest result of my mock

Answer (score 3):

You cannot (you could, but it is not worth the trouble). `BindingResult` is an object that Spring will create when it creates your command object and pass it when it invokes your `saveCandidate` handler method.

You shouldn't be testing classes and objects that Spring provides, you should be testing how they are resolved when you input right or wrong request parameters.

---

To explain why it's not worth it:

Spring uses a stack of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, and `HandlerMethod` instances, among others, to handle the request that arrives at the `DispatcherServlet`. Mocking a `BindingResult` would very likely mean having to mock or subclass all of those.

Comment: Please explain me how can I pass @ModelAttribute("candidateFromRequest") @Validated()  Candidate candidateFromRequest   ?

Comment: I want to pass it with invalid data

Comment: @user2740224 You can't do that either. Spring generates that object from your request parameters. Send bad request parameters.

Comment: @user2740224 My answer has to do with `MockMvc`. You can always just unit test your controller directly and pass whatever you want.

Comment: I want to check that with valid and invalid data I will get status().isOk()

Comment: @user2740224 You aren't using the `MockMvc` API correctly if you are trying to pass mocks to it. It's meant for integration testing. Pass data that you would actually use in production environment.

Comment: "Pass data that you would actually use in production environment" I don't understand you

Comment: @user2740224 Use the `MockMvc` as though you were a client device sending requests. For example, through a browser. You would use the `MockMvc` to send the same data the browser would send.